# uplodify onUploadSuccess not working

Tags: jquery

file is uploading nicely but onUploadSuccess is not running after upload is finish what can the problem

```
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery('#app-icon').uploadify({
            'uploader':'../wp-content/themes/canvas/admin/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
            'script':'../wp-content/themes/canvas/admin/uploadify/uploadify.php',
            'cancelImg':'../wp-content/themes/canvas/admin/uploadify/cancel.png',
            'folder':'../wp-content/themes/canvas/admin/uploadify/uploads',
            'auto':true,
            'fileExt':'*.jpg;*.gif;*.png',
            'fileDesc':'Web Image Files (.JPG, .GIF, .PNG)',
            'queueSizeLimit':3,
            'simUploadLimit':3,
            'method':'POST',
            'sizeLimit':10240000,
            'removeCompleted':false,
            'onUploadSuccess' : function(file, data, response) {
                alert('The file ' + file.name + ' was successfully uploaded with a response of ' + response + ':' + data);
                jQuery("#file-name").val(file.name);
            }
        });
    });
```